# Delete incomplete downloads with s3cmd

Tags: download, s3cmd

I'm using s3cmd on a network with bad Internet connection. Sometimes, it stops in the middle of a sync resulting in half finished files/corrupted files. Normally, I'd like it to simply continue where it paused, but in this case due to various reasons I don't want to have incomplete downloads.

Is there any way of telling s3cmd to never save local files that haven't been completely downloaded, and instead start over next time it's time to sync?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use https://github.com/minio/mc to delete incomplete uploads

```
$ mc ls https://s3.amazonaws.com/<yourbucket> incomplete

You can selectively delete on or recursively all incomplete uploads

$ mc rm https://s3.amazonaws.com/<yourbucket>/... incomplete force
```

To continue from where left off `mc` already implements session based uploads for any network disconnection and willful termination. `mc` saves local sessions of your copy/mirror operation.

You can easily resume them as well with

```
$ mc session resume <resume_id>
```